# pass statusbar text to dxAlertWindowManager1

Tags: delphi, devexpress, tms

How can I pass AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[0].Text to dxAlertWindowManager1?

I would like a similar display :

> dxAlertWindowManager1.Show('Greetings',
>   'AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[0].Text' , 0);

Comment: Er, replace `'AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[0].Text'` with `AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[0].Text`?

Comment: strange thing ...first time I tried it on form show (like you suggested) it did not work...Then I realised that the form gets shown before the query gets the result in the status bar. So it kept misfiring when run for the first time. Now I realise where the problem was. Thank you david, you can post the above as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace

```
'AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[0].Text'
```

with

```
AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[0].Text
```

The former is a string literal, the latter is the expression that yields the status bar text.